# Prepopulate a Set of tasks

Tags: related-list, tasks, automation

**Background:**

I am currently undertaking my first sf project here at work. We are building a little tracking application for the projects we undertake here. I have an object with several related lists. Each of the related lists are separate objects within the app.

**Where I need help**

Each of the related list objects has a set of records that are all identical other than which project object entity they are related to. I wish to either at creation or hitting a button to **AUTO**-create those records. I am new (and still learning) but need a bit of help in which direction I should take in tackling this problem.

**Another way of looking at it**

Auto Create a set of tasks under an account either by hitting a button or when the account is created.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case of creating tasks when a record is created, simply go to Setup > Create > Workflow & Approvals > Workflow Rules and create a new rule to create those tasks. You'll want to take a peek at the Help for this page in the Workflow Rules area for more information on how these work. There's no need to write code unless you want to do so from the click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Workflow Rules you could also use the Process Builder to generate the tasks.

[image: Example]